# Why dose File.Exists not work for exe's and shortcuts

Tags: c#, search, directory

Why is `File.Exists` not returning true, no matter what filename I feed into it. Here is my code below

```
using System;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MainClass
        static void Main()
        {
        string filename = "Firefox";
         if(File.Exists(filename)  ){
         Console.WriteLine("true");
         }
          else{Console.WriteLine("False"); }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing `filename` variable to a directory, and even a different file name but it still returns false. I'm 100% sure that the files are in the directory

Comment: I edited it, it is no longer a duplicate

Comment: Are you specifying the entire filename including extension? E.g. `@"C:\Program Files\Mozilla\Firefox\firefox.exe"`

Comment: I just tried that. Thanks. Your soultion worked. Specifying the file name returned true

Comment: Specifying the file extension worked. Thanks